# calling a template and return it as a string in django from view

Tags: python, django, pdf

In my django project I want to call my template with from views.py with a list view and return it like a string in my view function. This is because I want to print the string as an pdf. Is it possible to call the template with context_object_name so it can generate the html page and then return it an an string to my pdf generator, weasyprint?

views.py:

```
def eprint(request):

    g=request.GET
    checked=g.getlist('marked[]')
    print(checked)

    res=[Concert.objects.get(pk=l) for l in checked] 

    con='<table class="table table-hover table w-auto text-xsmall cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" table-striped table-sm">'

    paragraphs=['first paragraph', 'second paragraph', 'third paragraph']
#    html_string=render_to_string('test', {'paragraphs': paragraphs})

    hres=render(request,'events.html',{'cc':res})
    html=HTML(string=hres)
#    html=HTML(string=html_string)
    html.write_pdf(target='pdf/test.pdf');

    fs = FileSystemStorage('pdf')
    with fs.open('test.pdf') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'
        return response
    
    return response

class Events(ListView):

    context_objecjt_name='cc'
    model=Concert
    template_name='kammem/events.html'
```

events.html:

```
{% for l in object_list %}
  <tr>
<td>
  <form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id={{l.pk}} name="checkb"></label>
  <form>
</td>
    <td><a href="eupdate/{{l.pk}}"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="edelete/{{l.pk}}"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></a></td>
    <td>{{l.pk}}</td>
    <td>{{l.cname}}</td>
    <td><a href="detail/{{l.venue.pk}}">{{l.venue}}</a></td>
    <td>{{l.date}}</td>
    <td><a href="detail/{{l.organizer.pk}}">{{l.organizer}}</a></td>
    <!-- <td><a href="detail/{{l.vadress.pk}}">{{l.vname}}</a></td> -->
    <!-- <td>{{l.organizer}}</td> -->
<td>{{l.antmus}}</td>
<td>{{l.män1}}/{{l.kvinnor1}}</td>
<td>{{l.publik}}</td>
<td>{{l.män2}}/{{l.kvinnor2}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I see you tried using `render_to_string` from the comment in your code, what doesn't work with that?

Comment: I don't know how to call and get the template bacl as a string.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I solved it.

```
hres=render(request,'events.html',{'cc':res})
hres=hres.serialize()
html=HTML(string=hres)
html.write_pdf(target='pdf/test.pdf');
```

res is the list of pk's to iterate over, render takes care of the rendering.